# Why does one of these queries run so slowly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run the following 4 queries in Postgres 9.1, I get very puzzling results.  Queries 1, 2, and 4 behave as expected, returning results quickly, but query 3 takes significantly longer to run.

plant_data is a table with ~67 million records, and is indexed with btree indexes in all the expected ways.

```
-- Query 1
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE sensor_id IN (
    SELECT name FROM nomenclature 
    WHERE resolution = '1DAY' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
```

Uses index, runs in < 14ms (returns 0)
http://explain.depesz.com/s/dx9

```
-- Query 2
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE sensor_id IN (
    SELECT name FROM nomenclature 
    WHERE resolution = '1DAY' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1)
```

Also uses index, runs in < 14ms (returns 29)
http://explain.depesz.com/s/Zfl

```
-- Query 3
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE sensor_id IN (
    SELECT name FROM nomenclature 
    WHERE resolution = '1DAY' LIMIT 2)
```

Does seq. scan, runs in 261 seconds (returns 29)
http://explain.depesz.com/s/Xui

```
-- Query 4
select count(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE sensor_id IN (
   'BUR_PCLo_SAMPww_C_COD_1DAY',   -- First 2 results in
   'BUR_ANDIi1_FLOraw_I_VOL_1DAY') -- nomenclature table
```

Uses index, runs in < 14ms, (returns 29)
http://explain.depesz.com/s/iQc

Question: Why doesn't query 3 use an index and return results quickly?

---

The data in the table tends to follow a fairly regular pattern.  Broadly, there are 4 groups of data... First is a chunk that tends to come in blocks of 2800 entries with the same sensor_id.  The second comes in blocks of 96 values with the same sensor_id.  The third comes in blocks of 12 with the same sensor_id, and the fourth comes in blocks of 1.  We tend to get ~50 type 1 followed by ~50 type 2 followed by ~50 type 3 followed by a handful of type 4, before looping back to the beginning.  The data in the queries above is all type 4 (chosen because the result sets are manageable for running queries manually).

**To summarize**, the data we are selecting tends to be diffusely dispersed across our 67 million records.

---

The full table and index structure:

```
CREATE TABLE plant_data
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  date timestamp without time zone,
  sensor_id text,
  value double precision,
  day_id integer,
  week_id integer,
  month_id integer,
  year_id integer,
resolution integer 
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE plant_data
  OWNER TO inners_data;

CREATE INDEX plant_data_date_index
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (date);

CREATE INDEX plant_data_day_id
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (day_id);

CREATE INDEX plant_data_month_id
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (month_id);

CREATE INDEX plant_data_resolution_idx
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (resolution);

CREATE INDEX plant_data_sensor_id_date_index
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (date, sensor_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX plant_data_sensor_id_index
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (sensor_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX plant_data_week_id
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (week_id);

CREATE INDEX plant_data_year_id
  ON plant_data
  USING btree
  (year_id);
```

Edits: Updated explains above to be explain analyze, added info about indexes, table structure, and data patterns within the table

Comment: Please add the execution plans (ideally uploaded to http://explain.depesz.com)

Comment: This is intriguing. Please share the query plans. See [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) for instructions on generating a query plan.

Comment: I attached query plans to each query.

Comment: Can you get the plans using "explain analyze", rather than just "explain"?  Those are often much more useful.

Comment: **Please show us your table layouts and indexes.** Paraphrasing with "all the expected ways" is making the assumption that you have made no mistakes anywhere in your tables or indexes.  The shape of the rows can also make a difference.

Comment: FYI, this sort of thing is better suited to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Added full table description, list of indexes, and an explanation of what we expect the data to look like within the table.  Also updated all the links to explain data above to show results of explain analyze.

Answer (score 2):

Does the following run fast or slow?

```
-- Query 1
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM nomenclature 
              WHERE resolution = '1DAY' and sensor_id = name LIMIT 2
             );
```

First, Postgres is going to be smart about an `in` list with constants. It is not surprising that the fourth returns quickly. For the first two examples, I suspect (or perhaps this example proves) that Postgres optimizes a subquery that returns one row differently from a subquery that returns multiple rows. That is, the first query is recognized to return one row and is optimized as if it were:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE sensor_id = (
    SELECT name FROM nomenclature 
    WHERE resolution = '1DAY' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
```

However, with multiple rows, Postgres takes a different approach that probably involves reexecuting the inner query each time. Does this query go fast or slow?

```
-- Query 2
with list as (
    SELECT name FROM nomenclature 
    WHERE resolution = '1DAY' LIMIT 2
   )
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE sensor_id IN (select name from list);
```

EDIT:

Your explains do explain what the difference in performance is. With `limit 1`, Postgres is doing a nested loop join, which happens to be *real* fast when there is only one row to loop through. It would also be *real* fast looping through two rows. As part of the nested loop, it is using the index on `resolution`.

In the `limit 2` case, Postgres is choosing to do a "hash-semi join". That means that the data in the larger table needs to processed. Worse, the data is not coming from the index, but instead the entire table is being scanned. Arrrg!

I don't know why the Postgres optimizer is so subooptimal in this case, avoiding a totally reasonable index.

Comment: Both are slow.  I did not let either run to completion, but could do so if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Tangentially, your subselect is doing a limit without an order by.  This is a bad practise, as the results of such a query are indeterminate.  (And also might confuse the planner)

Your queries think they are going to find 700,000 rows, but actually only find 0 or 29.  It is not surprising that postgres underestimates the value of an index when it thinks the selectively is so different than it really is.

What is the distribution of sensor_id within your table?  There is probably a huge skew in that distribution.  If you drive the skew high enough, you might even get to the point that it would choose the seq scan even in the case of a LIMIT of 1.

Basically your subselect is returning only rare sensor_id (will that always be the case?) and not the very common ones, but postgresql doesn't know that ahead of time.

Increasing default_statistics_target and analyzing might help, but I wouldn't hold my breathe on that.  Upgrading to 9.2 or 9.3 might help as well, as "index only scans" could be effective here.

Alas, the safest thing might be just to run the subselect separately, and then assemble query 4 based on the results of it.

Comment: I tried adding an ORDER BY clause to Query 3, which did not help.  The query SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM plant_data 
WHERE sensor_id IN (
    SELECT name FROM nomenclature 
    WHERE resolution = '1DAY' ORDER BY name
    LIMIT 2
    )  still runs slow, and still does a sequential scan.  Did I put the right ORDER BY clause in?

Comment: Also, I added info about the data distribution to my original post; basically, the records I am selecting are evenly distributed over the entire 67M record dataset.

Comment: Regarding the distribution, I mean how many records of each sensor_id there are, not how they are physically scattered throughout the table.  If I understand your description of the "groups", each sensor_id value shows up in only one of those "groups".  In that case, the planner would be a lot better able to deal with it if each group was its own table.  What benefit do you get from mingling them?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is just that PostgreSQL isn't great with the construct:

```
WHERE sensor_id IN (
    SELECT name FROM nomenclature 
    WHERE resolution = '1DAY' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
```

`OFFSET` acts as an *optimization fence*, preventing PostgreSQL from restructuring the query into a more efficient form. This is made worse by the lack of an `ORDER BY` to make the query unambiguous.

In general, it's much clearer to write such queries with `EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM nomenclature n
    WHERE n.resolution = '1DAY'
    AND sensor_id = n.name)
```

For detailed comment on the reasons for the behaviour, I think you'll need to post to the pgsql-performance mailing list. I'm currently working on the query planner code, but not the optimizer logic, and only someone who really knows the optimizer well can probably really answer this one well.

Comment: I tried the following query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM plant_data 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM nomenclature n
    WHERE n.resolution = '1DAY'
    AND sensor_id = n.name)

Comment: @Watusimoto ... and what happened?

Comment: What happened is StackOverflow wouldn't let me update my comment to add the results!!

Comment: The query ran as slowly as Query 3 in my original post.  Explain shows that it does a sequential scan over the whole table, and does not use any of my indexes.

Comment: @Watusimoto No, that's not the same as your Query 3 above. Read it again. It uses `EXISTS` not `IN (...)`.

Comment: I understand the query is different; I only mean to say that it is less efficient than than Query 1, which is identical in function, and which I would expect to behave the same way.